# Using JSON object values in PostgreSQL GIN index

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, indices

I want to create a trgm GIN index on all the values in my JSONB object `obj`.

The first approach I came up with is this:

```
CREATE INDEX table_values_idx ON table
    USING GIN (array_to_string(
        (SELECT value FROM jsonb_each_text(obj)), ' ') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Of course, the above doesn't work, because subqueries (`SELECT`) can not be used in PostgreSQL indices.

Is there another way to join the values of a JSONB object without the use of a subquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to define your custom function for this, because the built-in `json[b]` functions all return `setof sometype`.

```
create or replace function jsonb_values(jsonb)
  returns text array
  language sql
  immutable
as $func$
  select case jsonb_typeof($1)
    when 'null'   then array[]::text[]
    when 'object' then array(select v from jsonb_each($1) e, unnest(jsonb_values(e.value)) v)
    when 'array'  then array(select v from jsonb_array_elements($1) e, unnest(jsonb_values(e)) v)
    else array(select v from jsonb_build_array($1) a, jsonb_array_elements_text(a) v)
  end
$func$;
```

http://rextester.com/GSTHZ3132

With this, you could create an index, like:

```
CREATE INDEX table_values_idx ON table
  USING GIN (array_to_string(jsonb_values(obj), ' ') gin_trgm_ops);
```

After that, you can use this index for your `LIKE` and FTS queries:

```
select *
from   table
where  array_to_string(jsonb_values(obj), ' ') like '%abc%'
```

Comment: Thanks, although it seems like cheating because the SELECT appears in the function as well ;-) I adopted a variant of your solution and it seems to work.

Comment: @lue3Seba unfortunately, it cannot be solved without a `SELECT` in the function. This variant also handles inner arrays and objects, but if you don't need that, sure you could simplify it. I just tried to think of any possibility.